# Which registers do x86/x64 processors use for floating point math?

Tags: floating-point, x86, 64-bit, simd, cpu-registers

Does x86/x64 use SIMD register for high precision floating point operations or dedicated FP registers?

I mean the high precision version, not regular `double` precision.

Comment: "High precision" is all done by software. The processor knows nothing beyond double precision and extended precision in the x87 FPU.

Comment: @Mysticial - every processor I know of has FP registers with resolution beyond 64 bit for internal operations to minimize approximation errors.

Comment: Those "internal" registers aren't accessible to the software. They are only slightly larger than 53/64 bits so that the final result is accurate to 53/64 bits. The multiplication ones might be as large as 106/128 bits before rounding. But you can't access them.

Comment: @Mysticial - aren't FP registers accessible in assembly? I am simply asking if modern CPUs still use dedicated 80bit FP registers or use the widely used and wider SSE/2/AVX/2 registers for even higher precision?

Comment: You can access the registers that the instruction set exposes. These include the x87 FPU/SSE/AVX. But there aren't higher precision versions of those that the software can use. Yes, internally, the processor may have higher precision registers, but they are only for internal operations which will all be rounded to 53/64 bits upon getting put back into an ISA accessible register.

Comment: @user2341104: If you take a look at the SSE/AVX instruction sets, you'll see that there aren't any instructions for larger-than-64-bit arithmetic. There is no support for higher-precision operations using the SIMD register set.

Comment: @Mysticial Correctly-rounded multiplication is implemented with three additional bits to the width of the result, the last of which is specially wired (“sticky bit”). Scroll down to “sticky” on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: @PascalCuoq Ah. That's good to know. Thanks! Though I suppose that FMAs will need the full double-width?

Comment: @Mysticial I have been wondering about a close variation of this question recently. My version was: would it be more expensive to offer double -> quad or double -> double double multiplication than FMA, reducing the idiom r1 = x * y; r2 = fma(x, y, -r1) to a single operation? I don't have the answer…

Comment: @PascalCuoq Could you expand a bit on what you mean by double -> quad, and double -> double double? I don't think I know that notation.

Comment: @Mysticial I simply meant some form of multiplication that produced wider output than its input, as is traditional with integers (32-bit integer multiplication producing a 64-bit result on two registers). “double double” is a format to represent numbers with near-quad-precision, using double-precision hardware.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Ah ic. Yeah, I don't think I can come of with an answer either... I'm not entirely sure how FMAs are done in the first place. I should probably read up on that first.

Answer (score 1):

The FPU stack is still available and exposes a 80-bits precision arithmetic as @EricPostpischil points out (not sure though if the processor still has the full logic or if this part got emulated at hardware level). It is made available to the developper in GCC with the `long double` type. For example, the generated assembly for method

```
long double f(long double a, long double b)
{
    return a*b ;
}
```

Will be

```
    fldt    16(%rbp)
    fldt    32(%rbp)
    fmulp   %st, %st(1)
```

This [archive email](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2000-05/msg00529.html) provides useful elements for using such data e.g.:

> ```
> long double my_logl(long double x)
> {
>   long double y;
>   __asm__ volatile(
>     "fldln2\n"
>     "fldl   %1\n"
>     "fyl2x"
>     : "=t" (y) : "m" (x));
>   return y;
> }
> ```

When compiling code without SSE, AVX or other vector extension, your code will likely generate such instructions using the 80bits FPU, and probably will output different values. Here is an example code to illustrate:

```
double epstest(long double a, long double b)
{
        long double y ;
        y = a + b ;
        y = y - a ;
        return y ;
}

#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
        double x = 1.0 ;
        double y = 1e-17 ;
        double z = x + y ;
        z = z - x ;
        printf ("double: %lf + %le - %lf = %le\n",  x, y, x, z);
        double res = epstest (x, y) ;
        printf ("long double: %lf + %le - %lf = %le\n",  x, y, x, res);
        return 0 ;
}
```

And the output:

```
double: 1.000000 + 1.000000e-17 - 1.000000 = 0.000000e+00
long double: 1.000000 + 1.000000e-17 - 1.000000 = 9.974660e-18
```

Higher precision (beyond `long double`) is implemented in software for x86_64.

Comment: x87 still has high performance on current-generation x87 CPUs, as you can see from [Agner Fog's insn tables](http://www.agner.org/optimize/).  On Skylake, for example, `fadd` is 3c latency, one per 1c throughput (and runs on port5!).  Only the complex x87 insns (like fsin) are microcoded.  Even `fsqrt` is fast.  Load/store of 80bit floats is very slow, though.

Comment: By comparison, on Skylake, `addps`/`addss` are 4c latency, one per 0.5c throughput.  (SSE/AVX add/sub/mul/fma on Skylake all have the same performance, since they dropped the lower-latency dedicated add unit that was present until Broadwell.)

Comment: Also, you don't have to use `-O0` or anything dumb like that.  The x86-64 SysV ABI specifies that `long double` is the 80 bit x87 type, so code using that type is required to have that much precision.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I basically consider x87 obsolete. Why would anyone use x87 e.g. with a Skylake processor?

Comment: @Zboson: It's by far the fastest way to get 80-bit precision floats.  Also, I can't remember which glibc function, but I'm sure I saw one that used x87 for something, on purpose with hand-written asm, for some simple x87 instruction (not like fsin).  While trying to find it again, I did find glibc's `difftime` implementation, which uses `long double` to get a `double` difference between two `time_t` integers.  `time_t` is signed on x86-64, so glibc is actually being silly here.  An FP type that can exactly represent every 64bit integer is interesting.  `FILD m64int` exists even in 32bit.

Comment: Forgot to link [glibc's `difftime(3)`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/time/difftime.c) implementation.  I think they'd get the same results with better code if they checked if `time_t` was signed, and if so just did the subtraction in `time_t` and then converted to `double`.  So this doesn't really count as a good use-case for x87.

Answer (score 0):

The FPU (Floating-Point Unit) has registers for 80-bit floating-point values (in an Intel format that is the IEEE 754 format with slight changes).

The various SIMD units (SSE, AVX et cetera) have larger registers that are usable for a number of things, but there are only instructions for using them as 32-bit and 64-bit floating-point.